# Compare 2 different Lists between List<XElement> and List<String>

Tags: c#, linq

I got a XElement list like this:

```
List<XElement> x = rootx.Elements("table").Elements("row").Where(row => row.Elements("column").ElementAt(1).Value == "1").ToList<XElement>();
```

then I got another String list like this:

```
List<String> CoList = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("id")).ToList();
```

How can i make a new XElement list to **exclude** the items in x that not found in CoList?

> For example, if x contains { a, b, c, d} and CoList contains { a, c,
>   d}, how can i return a new x that contains { a, c, d} ?

Is there a simple way to do this? Tks

Comment: I don't understand your example.  You said you wanted to *exclude* elements that appear in X but not in CoList.  So if X is `{a, b, c, d}` and CoList is `{a, c, d}` then you want to exclude `b`, right?  But `b` appears in your example result `{a, b, d}`.  Did you mean to say `{a, c, d}`?

Comment: Yup, Brian you are correct! Tks and I have made the changes to my example above. I mean {a, c, d} as the final output.

Comment: Hi Brian, I saw you posted a comment relating to XElementEqualityComparer method but now the comment got deleted. Just wondering if the XElementEqualityComparer method will be efficient if the list contains 1000+ entries? Tks

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized it didn't really answer the question you were asking.  My answer was assuming you were comparing two lists of XElements.  But now that I've reread the question I see you're really comparing a list of XElements with a list of strings.  So an XElementEqualityComparer doesn't apply here.  I guess my question is, how do you consider an XElement to be equal to a string?  Do you just do `.ToString` on the XElement?  Or do you take the tag name?  Or the Value?

Comment: @Trowa for efficient comparison you can use `HashSet<string>` instead of `List<String>`

Comment: Hi @BrianRogers I'm comparing with the Value.
so eventually, i come out with something like this:

List<XElement> x1 = x.Where(y => CoList.Contains(y.Elements("column").ElementAt(0).Value)).ToList<XElement>();

Comment: Hi @Slai How to do that using HashSet ?

Comment: `var CoList= new HashSet<string>(ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["id"] + ""))`

Comment: Tks for the comment @Slai , i will consider that = )

Comment: @Slai @Trowa you can just use `.ToHashSet()` instead of `.ToList()`

Comment: @Danny do I need to add an extension class for .ToHashSet() method? I found more info here: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/31/c.net-toolbox-adding-a-tohashset-extension-method.aspx

Comment: @Trowa sorry I guess you do. The codebase I work in must have it in an extension class, I just assumed it was part of Linq. Doing `newHashSet(...)` is fine though.

Comment: Yup understand @Danny, tks for clarification anyway = )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to convert y to a string in a more sophisticated way but this is the gist of it

```
var newList = x.Where(y => CoList.Contians(y.ToString()));
```

Comment: List<XElement> x1 = x.Where(y => CoList.Contains(y.Elements("column").ElementAt(0).Value));

but i got error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

how to solve this?

Comment: I have resolved it by adding .ToList<XElement>(); at the end of my code above.

Comment: @Trowa feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it solved the problem.